# Does an event loop keep running the program's code in PyQt/PySide?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, event-loop

I know that when creating a QApplication, an evet loop is created.
Does this mean that application will keep running the codes for ever untill it's terminated?
I was trying to call a slot in my Main class constructor and i wondered if that slot would keep executing since there is an event loop thus the Main class would be instantialized for ever.
How am i wrong? Why is the consructor method run only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event loop is just an infinite loop that pulls events off of a queue and processes them.

```
def exec_():
    while True:
        event = event_queue.get()
        process_event(event)
```

The event loop is run when you call the "exec_()" method. When you click or interact with the GUI you are putting an event on the event queue. Qt internally processes that event.

You will also notice that a long running button click will halt the GUI. Everything is running synchronously. When a button is clicked that event is being processed. No other events are processed while that event is running.

```
import time
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

def halt_10_sec():
    time.sleep(10)  # Stay here for 10 seconds

btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Halt')
btn.clicked.connect(halt_10_sec)
btn.show()

app.exec_()  # Run forever until app.quit()

# You will not get here until all windows are closed and the application is exiting.
print('Here')
```

Once you click the button you will not be able to resize the window, move the window, highlight the button on hover, or any other events while the button event is running.

A slot is just a function. You should be able to call a slot in the constructor.

Comment: Instantiation of the main is done before app.exec_(). So the constructor method runs once, and then we have the event loop, which waits for any signals by the user. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, the event loop waits for signals and events. If you need concurrency you can use threading or timers.

Comment: i thought an evet loop keeps running the code from top to buttom thus running the constructor for ever,  which is wrong. An EVENT loop is a loop of EVENTS(signals...) And it does not mean that the codes above it will cobtinuously execute. Thanks

Comment: @Sherafati "An EVENT loop is a loop of EVENTS(signals...)": not exactly. It's a loop that *waits* for *any* event (usually user events, but also timed or system events), and, after processing the first available event, it starts again (hence, *loop*) waiting for more events in the queue; if there are more queued events waiting, they will be processed (usually in their insertion order), otherwise it will just wait.